# Trick the suggested edit queue to force reject items

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review-queues, suggested-edits

I just realized that it is possible to reject an edit suggestion without the votes from other users, without any special privileges or >20k reputation.

Steps to take on any item in the queue:

1. Click on "Improve"
2. Remove the made edits (copy and paste the original markdown)
3. Uncheck the checkbox "Suggested edit was helpful"
4. Click "Save Edits"

Then the Community user will reject the post with the reason:

> Community♦ reviewed this 3 mins ago: Reject
>
> Conflicted with a subsequent edit.

This causes that a suggested edit is immediately rejected an will ne never showed up to anybody in the queue later.

Is this a bug? Or by design?

Comment: I believe the overall behaviour is by design, but I don't have a reference for that to hand. Someone else might. It does seem a little odd that it doesn't check to see if you've actually changed anything though.

Comment: @JonK But isn't that dangerous? Bad users could start rejecting every suggestion.

Comment: This is by design. You can also go to the post revision history, pick edit there, and submit a new edit. That'd also kill the suggested edit (community would then also reject it).

Comment: @wumm: bad users can do all sorts of things. Just not very long; a temporary suspension is easily earned with such behaviour.

Comment: @wumm: Those 'bad users' would first have to gain 2k reputation first, of course, because you cannot review with less.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, I know that. But does such a behavior show up to moderators? And theoretically a user can earn 2k in ten days.

Comment: @wumm: *why* would a user do that? To troll? Trolls are lazy, they want a quick fix. Noone carefully gains 2000 points first just to go reject suggested edits. It doesn't matter really how a moderator finds out about this; with a large and alert community like we have here they don't need automated means even.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You have to ask trolls why they troll. I don't know.

Comment: @wumm: as stated before, there are plenty of ways the system can be trolled, this would be one of them. We cannot put blocks against any and all anticipated bad behaviour in place, that'd make the legitimate uses impossible. The likelyhood of anyone abusing this are slim, and if someone does anyway the damage is limited (the suggested edits can be manually applied) and easily remedied (the troll is suspended).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Okay, I don't think really someone is going to troll this way but I thought it maybe a risk since this edit suggestion is never seen again anywhere, is it? (If you don't have a link)

Comment: @wumm: the review queue history tab has links (the full history is visible to 10k+ users and moderators), as does the activity tab of the user that suggested the edit.

Comment: I've just had an edit rejected by Community with the reason "This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit", which has (imho unfairly) doubled my rejected edit count. I was presented with a new user question in the review queue, and edited it to format the code and remove the signature. The OP appears to have retained my content changes and edit reason, but rejected or overwritten my edit. I'm puzzled as to why I get a black mark for an action after mine? Is this what we're discussing here or should I raise a new question? (Link: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6116219 )

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is by design. Your 'Improve' edit adds a new revision to the post, automatically making it impossible for the suggested edit to be applied.

Note that it is the *Community User* that rejects the suggested edit. The same would happen if you went directly to the post, and in the revision history of that post clicked the 'edit' link on the most recent revision and submitted an edit.

Sure, this could be abused, but to what end? Rejecting all suggested edits in this manner for a while just to troll? That'll get you unwelcome moderator attention in a very short amount of time, a suspension is easily earned.